# What's wrong with storing user data in json files?

Tags: php, mysql, json, database, postgresql

All the answers about this question assume you're storing all of your user's data in one big file - and so they talk about how that is too slow.

Let's say I have thousands of users and store their data as JSON format in separate files (which I am currently doing), what is the downside to that - as opposed to setting up a proper database like Postgresql - which seems like overkill.

The speed is great on my current setup, but I am advised against doing this.

Since each user has their own separate file, there isn't really an issue of hundreds of people writing to the file at the same time (isolation).

Maybe it only matters for sites with millions of users?

Comment: File I/O is a performance killer in multi-user environments. It may be fast with 1 user, but it won't be like this with 10,000 users simultaneously accessing

Comment: @LarsStegelitz PHP's `file_get_contents()` is too slow? If the user is able to access the website in the first place when there's 10,000 simultaneous users (based on the server, not the database), why would that command cause any issues? If they are able to access it, isn't the performance issue minimal?

Comment: @LarsStegelitz In other words, if you are able to build infrastructure that can support 10,000 concurrent users, how would a `file_get_contents()` be much of an issue

Comment: Sorry, but this can't be discussed with only a few words. You may ask the person who advised against using files, or you search the internet about this topic. I would advise you the same: do not use files, use a database

Comment: @LarsStegelitz What do you mean a few words, someone could add an answer with unlimited words. No one can provide a valid answer on this for some reason, but it makes sense for sites with millions of users. `Search the Internet about this topic` - I have done so and answers assume you're storing everything in one big file

Comment: a hard disk has a specific through-put, which can get exhausted if too many files are served simulteaneously. databases cache thing in memory, which is like tenthousand times faster than a harddisk... it will also exhaust at some point, but it takes thousands times more paralell accesses than the file system. NOTHING is limitless!

Answer (score 2):

There is no **absolute** right or wrong.

If you will never need to take care of concurrent access to the same record (file) or you don't need to search through your records or scale to multiple servers, the solution is fine and even faster than accessing a database.

I would just recommend to properly [escape the user provided data](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json_simple/json_simple_escape_characters.htm), as JSON

Answer (score 2):

In most systems, the users don't merely have to exist, they have to do stuff. And that stuff would generally be represented in a database.  So you want the users to exist in the same system where the things they interact with exist.

What happens if your system crashes (power failure, for example) when a json file is half-way written out?  Will you be left with a broken JSON file for that user?  With databases, that should be taken care of automatically (you find either the old record, or the new one, not some truncation or mishmash).  If you roll your own database, you will have to go some way out of your way to verify that you do this in a safe manner.

How do you name your user files?  By the user's name?  What if different people have the same name?  What if their name has characters that can't be represented in file names?  By an account number you assign?  What happens if they forgot their account number and need to look it up by their human name? Do you then need to read and parse every user file to identify the correct one? Not that a database will magically make this free, but at least with a database you can just build an index with first having to invent and implement them.

You are basically reimplementing a database system from scratch, one feature at a time, as you discover the need for that feature.  You can do it, sure.  But why not use one that already exists?

> Since each user has their own separate file, there isn't really an issue of hundreds of people writing to the file at the same time (isolation).

What if one person writes to one file at the same time from two different browsers (or tabs)?

Comment: unix users database is a text file: /etc/passwd
sometimes, using a full featured database is overkill